# Convert list of JSON Object to single list on Mule DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-el, mule-esb

**Input:-**

```
[
  {
    "appName": "helloworld-1"
  },
  {
    "appName": "helloworld-2"
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
"appList": [ "helloworld-1" , "helloworld-2" ]
}
```

Can anyone guide me for data weave script for this ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DataWeave Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#multi-value-selector), you can apply the multi value selector. Multi value selector returns an array with all the values whose key matches the expression.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    appList : payload.*appName
}
```